# Laravel. Auth. FormRequest

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

Created a **FormRequest** named **ValidationRegister** to slightly change the standard registration controller. Since I saw most of the checks in the **Request**.

Here is the validation itself:

```php
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'surname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'gender' => ['nullable', 'string', 'max:10'],
            'birthday' => ['nullable', 'string'],
            'rules' => 'accepted',
        ];
    }
```

The essence of the question is how to replace the validation in the controller

Standard validation:

```php
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }
```

There were various attempts to do this, even reached the change of registration trait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file `App/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController`, you can overwrite the trait method `register`. For your custom logic to work, you probably also need to change the create method, to save your new validated fields.

```
public class RegisterController {    

    public function register(ValidationRegister $request)
    {
        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->validated())));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
            ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
}
```